# Recuperando textos digitados em EditText gerado em tempo de execução

Tags: android, edittext

Em meu projeto tenho alguns *EditText* sendo gerados em tempo de execução, o número de *EditText* é variável.
Preciso recuperar os textos digitados e armazenar em variáveis diferentes, para depois criar um objeto Json com isso.

Aqui está o método que utilizo para criar o *EditText*:

```
public View editText(String nmLabel, String tpRender) {
    EditText e = new EditText(getBaseContext());
    e.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // e.setHint("DATE");

    if(tpRender.equals("NUMBER")) {
        e.setHint("NUMBER");
    }
    else if(tpRender.equals("DATE")) {
        e.setHint("DATE");
    }
    else if(tpRender.equals("TEXT")) {
        e.setHint("TEXT");
    }
    e.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    e.setTextSize(20);

    return(e);
}
```

Como obtenho os textos digitados separadamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atribua um id diferente a cada um deles usando `e.setId(int id)`

Pode depois aceder a eles utilizando o método `findViewById()` da view(layout) onde eles foram inseridos.

Comment: Funcionou 100%, obrigado!